# Codeigntier 3.1, $this->db->insert() does not return id as expected

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am using CI3.1 and am trying to test for a successful insert into a database.  This is the call I make:

```
$this->MH_addressbook_model->company_create($submitted_data_array);
```

I found this in the bcit-ci github issues section that I thought would work:

```
insert always returns integer 0 if no primary key is set on the 
table (Mysql) or if there is no auto increment. If there is a 
primary key and it is set to auto increment, insert returns the 
id of the most recent entry for successful insert otherwise it 
returns false as defined
```

I have tried echo, `print_r()` and `var_dump()` around around

```
$this->MH_addressbook_model->company_create($submitted_data_array)
```

but I don't get anything.  I also can't see that it returns TRUE on a successful insert.  Interesting to note that the data is always successfully inserted.  This is my model:

```
function company_create($submitted_data_array){
    $this->db->insert('mh_company', $submitted_data_array);
}
```

How can I test for a successful insert to the database?

Comment: So maybe you get error that is not displayed? Turn on error reporting and DB errors

Comment: It is inserted successfully but I need get $this->db->insert() to return something to me to tell me programmatically (1, true, id, something) that it was successful.

Comment: Your `company_create` does not `return` anything. Is that a problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing `return`

```
function company_create($submitted_data_array){
    return $this->db->insert('mh_company', $submitted_data_array);
}
```